# Why I can't resize the last Column width by GridSplitter?

Tags: wpf

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="Red"></Border>
        <GridSplitter HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="5"></GridSplitter>
        <Border Background="Green" Grid.Column="1"></Border>
        <GridSplitter HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="5" Grid.Column="1"></GridSplitter>
        <Border Background="Blue" Grid.Column="2"></Border>
        <GridSplitter HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="5" Grid.Column="2"></GridSplitter>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And I found that I can't resize the last Column width by the last `GridSplitter`.

In addition, all the other `GridSplitter` are working well.

Why it turns out to be this? And how can I solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your Grid's RowDefinition as below (add an extra column with * as width to occupy remaining space).

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
```

This is how your final Xaml looks like (only the content portion)

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="Red"></Border>
        <GridSplitter HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="5"></GridSplitter>
        <Border Background="Green" Grid.Column="1"></Border>
        <GridSplitter HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="5" Grid.Column="1"></GridSplitter>
        <Border Background="Blue" Grid.Column="2"></Border>
        <GridSplitter HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="5" Grid.Column="2"></GridSplitter>
    </Grid>
```

Try and let us know if this is what you are looking for or need some other kind of help.